# Recording with different sampling rate and audio (16/24 bit)

Tags: audio-recording, sampling, downsampling

Is it possible with a proper audio interface to record audio samples and simultaneously save multiple files with different sampling rate on live when the source is the same, such as from a mic?

I have the same question regarding 16 and 24 bit audio.

If this is not possible, do you think I can safely re-sample a file from let's say 96kHz down to 48kHz, 16kHz, 12kHz and 8kHz.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can safely downsample and reduce the bitrate from a high quality recording, provided you use quality software to do it.

Of course, the lower sample rates and bit depth will impose limitations on the sound quality, and you will either get aliasing artifacts or anti-aliasing noise, depending on the settings you choose. Below 44.1kHz and 16 bit the degradation becomes progressively audible as you lower the bit depth and sample rate.